# Difference in executing Javascript using Rhino and ASE

Tags: javascript, android, rhino, ase

what is the difference between executing JS with Rhino and executing with ASE(Android Scripting Environment)? Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in advance!

Code snippet executed with Rhino:

```
bar();
function bar() {
 var a=20; var b=30; var c = 40;
 average = (a+b+c)/3; 
out.println(average);
}
```

Code snippet executed with ASE(from ASE website):

```
load("/sdcard/com.googlecode.rhinoforandroid/extras/rhino/android.js");
var droid = new Android();
droid.makeToast("Hello, Android!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The II option means we are executing the script in Android phone(using SL4A library). Whereas, the first option just prints the output on the console. We cannot see any output in the phone or emulator